# Novel Identification (circa 1970s) archeologists find a star map

Tags: story-identification

Looking for the name of a book I read in childhood.  It was about a team of archeologists who find a star map and search the galaxy for some ancient civilization.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the old Robert Silverberg novel [*Across A Billion Years*](http://majipoor.com/work.php?id=8).